# Image is showing in each Row?

Tags: android, image

I am implementing List view in my Activity. I am showing image in first row only. when I moves from that Activity to another Activity and press Back then this image is shown in all Row? what to do? any help will be Appreciated. Code is this. I am Retrieving image from Remote server.
if (convertView == null) {

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_list_items_row, null);
        viewHandler = new ListingViewHandler(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHandler);
        convertView
                .setBackgroundResource((position % 2) == 0 ? R.color.listViewAlternateColor1
                        : R.color.listViewAlternateColor2);
    }

    viewHandler = (ListingViewHandler) convertView.getTag();

    ImageView image = viewHandler.getImage();
     Bitmap a = downloadFile(imageUrl);

    if (position==0) {
        image.setImageBitmap(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour of `ListView` `Adapter`, it is because, `ListView` re-uses `View` as `converView` for row. So the `View` for position 0 is re-used, which is holding the image, so You have to remove that image for other postions, to do so, put an `else` condition also, to remove image for other positions, like this:

```
if (position==0) {
   image.setImageBitmap(a);
}
else
   image.setImageDrawable(null);  //to remove the image for all other rows
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i set image dynamic?if image is coming for first row then show it and if image is not coming for any of row then not show.showing for which image is coming from remote server and not for which is image is not coming.